# How to set set height of some cells manually when using UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for setting heights of my UITableView cells. For a filter functionality, I need to hide some cells, and I am going to hide them by setting their height to 0.

However when I override heightForRowAtIndexPath, I need to return some value for the rows I wanna automatically sized too. How do I set it ?

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
```

,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if shouldHideCell == true{
        return 0
    }else{
        return automaticHeight // I need a value here!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant question. Brilliant answers. So good to not be the only one! Thanks :-) :-) One million up votes, if only I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your case try to set the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in the method rather than in your `viewDidload` like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
     ....
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if shouldHideCell == true{
        return 0.0
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

I am hoping that you are using `autoLayouts` to work with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
And be aware that `heightForRowAtIndex` gets called before `cellForRow` method, so make sure your variable `shouldHideCell` is properly set before that.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` I suppose that you're using auto layout, right?
If you use auto layout you can "hide" your cell by changing constants of the constraint(s) that have height or intrinsic height.
Try this.

Comment: AND ALSO ROLL! Thank you.